# how to load objects from json file

Tags: python, json

I am trying to load simple objects from the json file. But i am getting error in it. below is my code and also the data in json format in db.txt file. I am calling the getAll() function of model.py from some other class.

file: model.py

```
import simplejson

class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, first_name = None, last_name = None):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name

    def name(self):
        return ("%s %s"%(self.first_name, self.last_name))

    @classmethod
    def getAll(self):
        database = open('db.txt', 'r')
        result = []
        json_list = simplejson.loads(database.read())
        print("json list {}".format(json_list))
        for item in json_list:
            print("item {}".format(item))
            print("type of item {}".format(type(item)))
            item = simplejson.loads(item)
            person = Person(item['first_name'], item['last_name'])
            result.append(person)
        return result
```

file: db.txt

```
[
    {
        "first_name":"first name",
        "last_name":"last name"
    },
    {
        "first_name":"first name 2",
        "last_name":"last name 2"
    }
]
```

ERROR (output):

```
json list [{'first_name': 'first name', 'last_name': 'last name'}, {'first_name': 'first name 2', 'last_name': 'last name 2'}]
item {'first_name': 'first name', 'last_name': 'last name'}
type of item <type 'dict'>
...
...
item = simplejson.loads(item)
...
...
KeyError: 0
```

Comment: why are you doing `item = simplejson.loads(item)`???

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga because i want to extract first_name, last_name and create object Person from it.

Comment: That doesn't make sense .... Why are you passing a `dict` to `.loads` which requires a JSON-valid `str`....???  In any case that is the source of your error. Just use the `dict`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga then what is the best way to create json file for this requirement.

Comment: The JSON file is fine as it is. You can literally simply delete this line: `item = simplejson.loads(item)` and your code will work as you are expecting it to. I still don't understand why you think that line is necessary, or what it is supposed to do.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga i was following some tutorial and on that the input json was not given, so i created by myself. but the code is copied from their website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`simplejson.loads(database.read())` parses the JSON all the way down. You don't need to do it at every level. Since `item` is already a dict, you can use it like one immediately.